# How to set the some specified time to ajax call ,So that if request is taking time retrieve the data ,It should come to the FAIL Block

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var ajaxRequest = new enyo.Ajax({

    cacheBust: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 8000,
    async: false,
    handleAs: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        // Data to connect to the external service.
        url: url
            method: 'GET',

        contenttype: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        content: 'username=l&pwd=p' + searchParams
    }),
    success: function (inSender, inResponse) {
    },
    fail: function (inSender, inResponse) {
    }

    ajaxRequest.go(ajaxRequest.data).response('success').error('fail');

};
```

lets say ,call to the webservice taking 5 to 6 seconds time or if there is slow internet connection ,How to redirect to fail block

Comment: You mean like... using the `timeout` property, which is currently set to 8 seconds in your code?

Comment: Yeah,If it takes more than 8 seconds to fetch the data,As soon as it reach 8 seconds control should come to the Fail Block else automatically it should come to Success.

Answer (score 0):

what about manually call to fail-callback-func, something like:

```
var getDataFail = true;

    function getData() {
        setTimeOut(fileCallbackFunc, 6000);
        $.ajax({
            url: yourURL,
            success: doneCallbck,
            error: doneCallbck,
            //other ajax params
        });
    }



    function fileCallbck() {
        if (getDataFail) {
            //your fail logic...
            console.error('get data fail');
        }
    }

    function doneCallbck() {
        getDataFail = false;
        console.error('get data done');
    }
```